# Restrict the sum of outputs in a neural network regression (Keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, activation-function

I'm predicting 7 targets, which is ratio from one value, so for each sample sum of all predicted values should be 1.
Except of using `softmax` at the output (which seems obviously incorrect) I just cant figure out other ways to restrict sum of all predicted outputs to be =1..
Thanks for any suggestuions.

```
input_x = Input(shape=(input_size,))
output = Dense(512, activation=PReLU())(input_x)
output = Dropout(0.5)(output)
output = Dense(512, activation=PReLU())(output)
output = Dropout(0.5)(output)
output = Dense(16, activation=PReLU())(output)
output = Dropout(0.3)(output)
outputs = Dense(output_size, activation='softmax')(output)
#outputs = [Dense(1, activation=PReLU())(output) for i in range(output_size)] #multioutput nn

nn = Model(inputs=input_x, outputs=outputs)
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',min_delta=0,patience=10,verbose=1, mode='auto')
opt=Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1-0.995)
nn.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=opt)
history = nn.fit(X, Y, validation_data = (X_t, Y_t), epochs=100, verbose=1, callbacks=[es])
```

Example of targets:

[image]

So, this is all ratios from one feature, sum for each row =1.
For example Feature - 'Total' =100 points, A=25 points, B=25 points, all others - 10 points. So, my 7 target ratios will be 0.25/0.25/0.1/0.1/0.1/0.1/0.1.

I need to train and predict such ratios, so in future, knowing 'Total' we can restore points from predicted ratios.

Comment: Can you actually write how this ratio is constructed and should be predicted? Its not obvious to me why softmax is wrong in this case.

Comment: Softmax can produce those rations, again I don't see why doing that would be wrong.

Comment: Yes, it's producing, but it seems that it's not best option. If I put last layer as multioutput with relu - I get better score on MAE, RMSE. Even though it's not always sum of predicted ratio's =1 and I can't restore actual points from this ratio.

Comment: That it produces different performance does not mean its wrong, I think in the end you do not have a programming problem here. You have to make sure that its predicting correctly before looking at losses and metrics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand your motivation, and also why "softmax won't cut it".

This is because softmax doesn't scale linearly, so:

```
>>> from scipy.special import softmax
>>> softmax([1, 2, 3, 4])
array([0.0320586 , 0.08714432, 0.23688282, 0.64391426])
>>> softmax([1, 2, 3, 4]) * 10
array([0.32058603, 0.87144319, 2.36882818, 6.4391426 ])
```

Which looks nothing like the original array.

Don't dismiss softmax too easy though - it can handle special situations like negative values, zeros, zero sum of pre-activation signal... But if you want the final regression to be normalized to one, and expect the results to be non-negative, you can simply divide it by the sum:

```
input_x = Input(shape=(input_size,))
output = Dense(512, activation=PReLU())(input_x)
output = Dropout(0.5)(output)
output = Dense(512, activation=PReLU())(output)
output = Dropout(0.5)(output)
output = Dense(16, activation=PReLU())(output)
output = Dropout(0.3)(output)
outputs = Dense(output_size, activation='relu')(output)
outputs = Lambda(lambda x: x / K.sum(x))(outputs)

nn = Model(inputs=input_x, outputs=outputs)
```

The `Dense` layer of course needs a different activation than `'softmax'` (relu or even linear is OK).

Comment: Of course, for this architecture to make sense, the training and validation sets (`Y`, `Y_t`) should also have this property - sum of every row should be = 1.

Comment: Thanks! I will try and compare both cases.

Comment: final regression solution failed - not converging.

Comment: one disadvantage is that with this Lambda layer, you cannot export the resulting model for other formats, for example porting it to Deep Learning 4 Java. It's a real shame there is no standard "divide by sum" activation in Keras that can be exported as a standard layer. Similar for a few other operations like logarithm and thresholding by percentiles of the data - which all require non-portable Lambdas.

Comment: Use APIs.. which will avoid the porting constraint